# Parser error in php? Can't nest array indexing (accessing a value in an array to look up another array) without kludging extra code

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, associative-array

```
while($assocArray = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    for ($j = 0; $j < $length; $j++)
    {
        $column = $fields[$j];                      // + works
        echo "$assocArray[$column]          ";      // +
        //echo "$assocArray[ $fields[$j] ]      ";  // - doesn't work, should be same
    }

echo "<br/>";
}
```

A similar problem was reported for numeric arrays, which supposedly was solved. I'm using a very new build of PHP (5.3.6) so it must be a separate bug. Generates parse error.

Comment: This isn't to do with 5.3.6, it's a parser error in 5.3.5 too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surround the whole expression with curly braces:

```
echo "{$assocArray[ $fields[$j] ]}      ";
```

FYI: This is partially a matter of taste, but personally, I prefer *not* inlining arrays, especially with nested arrays. Isn't this nicer?

```
echo $assocArray[ $fields[$j] ] . "      ";
```

Comment: The curly braces thing works! Thank you very much... but this seems pretty strange behaviour which I'm sure canot be part of the spec. Does the curly brace trick rear its head in other places?

Comment: @Ala: The curly braces are not a trick. Their use in strings are [documented in the PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
echo "$assocArray[{$fields[$j]}]";
```

Note the extra `{}` in there. PHP's parser is generally "not greedy" and will stop parsing variables much earlier than most other scripting languages. It's especially evident on multi-dimensional arrays:

```
$arr[1] = array();
$arr[1][2] = "Hi there"

echo "$arr[1][2]";  // actually outputs "Array[2]" instead of "Hi There"
echo "{$arr[1][2]}"; // outputs 'Hi There' as expected
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $assocArray[ $fields[$j] ];
```

If you really need the trailing whitespace, append something like

```
str_repeat(' ', 5);
```

Comment: Thanks! this workaround works too, but of course it is far from ideal to have to use a workaround in the first place! :).

Comment: @Ala: Its not a workaround, its just "the common way" (in contrast to the variable substitution in `"`) to output the values of variables. Of course, you don't need to use `str_repeat()`. The most simple way to append whitespaces, is to append whitespaces: `echo $assocArray[ $fields[$j] ] . '     ';`. ;) But I would omit the whitespaces, because it doesn't seem, that they have a meaning.